# Parsing URL query string with lodash

Tags: javascript, lodash

How can I parse URL string using only lodash functions without any callbacks inside?

Ex.

```
var rawUrl = “?a=b454&c=dhjjh&f=g6hksdfjlksd..”
```

My current solution is

```
var answer = _.reduce(_.split(_.replace(rawUrl,'?',''), '&'), function(result, ev) {
    (result[ev.split('=')[0]] || (result[ev.split('=')[0]] = [])).push(ev.split('=')[1]);
    return result;
}, {});
```

But still, one callback is present here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

to avoid callback use [`_.partial`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#partial), [`_.partialRight`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.2#partialRight) and other lodash methods to work with functions

```
_.chain(rawUrl)
    .replace('?', '') // a=b454&c=dhjjh&f=g6hksdfjlksd
    .split('&') // ["a=b454","c=dhjjh","f=g6hksdfjlksd"]
    .map(_.partial(_.split, _, '=', 2)) // [["a","b454"],["c","dhjjh"],["f","g6hksdfjlksd"]]
    .fromPairs() // {"a":"b454","c":"dhjjh","f":"g6hksdfjlksd"}
    .value()
```

Comment: Great answer. Thanks!

Comment: Cool! Using this with `window.location.href` I tweaked it to `_.chain(window.location.href).split('?').nth(1).split('&').map(_.partial(_.split, _, '=', 2)).fromPairs().value()`

Comment: This was useful.  A tweak to handle full urls is to use `.replace(/^.+\?/, '')` instead of `.replace('?', '')`

Answer (score 20):

I'm aware that you asked for a lodash solution, but maybe people who read the question might also want to look at **URLSearchParams**, it helped me using less code than the ES6 approach, and avoiding lodash.

```
const params = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
```

to access a query parameter called 'a'

```
let a = params.get('a');
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams

Answer (score 3):

Es6 way without lodash :

```
  const urlParsed =
    rawUrl.substring(rawUrl.indexOf("?") + 1)
          .split("&")
          .reduce(
            (memo, param) => ({
              ...memo,
              [param.split("=")[0]]: param.split("=")[1]
            }),
            {}
          );
```

Answer (score 3):

You can also use https://github.com/sindresorhus/query-string instead of creating your own version of this feature.

Answer (score 0):

this was years ago, but still want to add this for anyone will come cross,

```
url
    .replace('?', '')
    .split('&')
    .reduce((a, n) => {
        return { ...a, [n.split('=')[0]]: n.split('=')[1] };
    }, {});
```